# Chart JS legend label color is not getting changed to my desired/provided color while using generateLabel callback fn

Tags: chart.js, chart.js-datalabels

[image: Image to refer, Legend text color is black]

While using `generateLabel()` for some use case, but inn that case the legend text color are coming as black, I want to know if there's a way to get that done as well. As we know we can do many things with the help of `generateLabel()`.

The config I'm using:

```
{
        type: 'doughnut',
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        data: {
          labels: ['Historical', 'Dead Stock'],
          datasets: [
            <any>{
              backgroundColor: ['#d927d6', '#437cb5'],
              data: [65, 35],
              color: 'white',
              pointStyle: 'rect',
              datalabels: {
                anchor: 'center',
                color: 'white',
                font: {
                  size: 25,
                  weight: 'bold',
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          plugins: {
            tooltip: { enabled: true },
            legend: {
              display: true,
              labels: {
                padding: 40,
                font: { size: 24 },
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                usePointStyle: true,
                generateLabels: <any>function (chart: any) {
                  const labels = chart.data.labels;
                  const datasets = chart.data.datasets;
                  const visibility: any = [];
                  chart.options.plugins.legend.labels.color = 'white';

                  for (let i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
                    if (chart.isDatasetVisible(0) === false) {
                      visibility.push(true);
                    } else {
                      visibility.push(false);
                    }
                  }

                  return labels.map(function (label, index) {
                    const dataset = datasets[0];
                    const backgroundColor = dataset.backgroundColor[index];
                    const pointStyle = dataset.pointStyle;

                    // Customizing legend item appearance
                    return {
                      text: label,
                      fillStyle: backgroundColor,
                      strokeStyle: backgroundColor,
                      pointStyle: pointStyle,
                      index: index,
                      hidden: visibility[index],
                    };
                  });
                },
              },
              position: 'right',
            },
          },
        },
      }
```

**NOTE**: I tried this way because I need same pointStyle in legend, which was not working if I tried mentioning pointStyle: 'rect' inside dataset object and inside options -> plugins -> legend -> labels -> usePointStyle: true. But this didn't worked.

Comment: See https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/10855. The returned label object should contain the "fontColor" field.

Comment: Thanks! This issue has been resolved now.